# When making a new core release, how do mantainers tag the core modules and update their info files?

Tags: version-control

When Drupal maintainers make a new core release, how do they tag the core modules and update their info files?
I have noticed that all the core modules of Drupal 7.43 have a section in their info files that looks like this:

```
version = "7.43"
project = "drupal"
datestamp = "1456343506"
```

Is there an automated procedure that runs GIT to merge branches, tag releases and updates the info files accordingly?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is an automated process, [check below](https://www.drupal.org/node/542202#version):

> The version string will be added by drupal.org when a release is
>   created and a tarball packaged. However, if your module is not being
>   hosted on the drupal.org infrastructure, you can give your module
>   whatever version string makes sense (eg. see Release naming
>   conventions).

**NOTE: The above description is exact copy paste from Drupal.org link.**

Comment: Thank you for the link Yogesh. The third paragraph says "Because Drupal core uses a slightly different packaging process". Do you happen to know this process? I would like to implement into my own workflow and not manually tag my own modules.

Comment: No, I'm not sure about this process. But Drupal Core version is found in bootstrap.inc file in `VERSION` variable which I think might be used while release is created and a tarball packaged.